# How to authenticate/authorize in Azure AD Auth using MSAL in .NET

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

What I'm trying to do is after I login my azure credentials in MSAL login pop up, I will use the token to access authorize API.

I set up my Startup.cs below:

I use Microsoft.Identity.Web nuget package.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

My apsettings.json AzureAd is configured below:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-********",
    "TenantId": "de1ef02c-7cfa-46b8-a02b-********",
    "Audience": "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-********"
  }
```

In my controller I have 2 API.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> LoginAzure()
    {
        //To be put on appsettings.json
        string clientId = "2f0d9252-e207-4d7f-b4da-********";
        string tenantId = "de1ef02c-7cfa-46b8-a02b-********";

        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:5000")
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { };

        //Azure Login Success here
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        //I pass the AccessToken from the result. But I'm getting UnAuthorized.
        string authorizeResult = await "https://localhost:44328/weatherforecast/AuthorizeGet"
            .WithOAuthBearerToken(result.AccessToken)
            .GetStringAsync();

        return authorizeResult;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> AuthorizeGet()
    {
        return "Authorize";
    }
```

The LoginAzure is for calling the MSAL.

And the AuthorizeToken is an authorize api.

I can successfully get the access token after login in azure using MSAL. But if I use the access token to the Bearer Token and access the authorize API, I'm getting 401 Unauthorize.

Anything I missed out on my configuration? Or how do I set up properly my MSAL?

If I try to access the microsoft graph api with the access token, I can successfuly access it.

Comment: Anyway, I have solved it by adding Scopes in Azure AD and adding it on my MSAL

Comment: I would suggest either posting as a proper answer, or deleting the question.

Comment: Hello, I am working through this now. I agree it would be nice to see what you added in the scopes to get this to work -  I think I get what youre saying though - thanks for letting me know!

PS. You are using PublicClientApplication, but it appears you are implementing AzureAD in a ConfidentialApplication since this is C# code behind that lives on a server